# Gmail - move email to a category

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I want to use Google Script to move an email to a specified category (e.g. Updates). How do I do this? I tried treating categories as labels, but that does not work.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code and describe any issues you are having with your solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Gmail Advanced API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail) in Apps Script to apply a category on email.

```
Gmail.Users.Threads.modify({"addLabelIds": ["CATEGORY_UPDATES"]}, userId, threadId)
```

You can also try the Rest API [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/modify)